# есть цикл, нужно из него вывести самое большое нечётное число

Tags: javascript

```js
for(i = 10; i<100;i++){
    if(i%2!==0){
        console.log(i)
   //смог вывести только нечётные числа,99 вывести не получается
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается. Перепроверьте

Comment: @Miron,нужно вывести только 99

Comment: i = 99; i >= 10; i-- . В блоке if после console.log(i) напишите break

Comment: в чем смысл данной задачи? Не легче ли 1) найти максимальное нечетное число 2) вывести это число. Зачем тут цикл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var maxNum = 0;
for(i = 10; i<100;i++){
    if(i%2!==0 && maxNum < i)  maxNum = i;
}
console.log(maxNum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let i = 100; i >= 10; i--) {
  if (i % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log(i);
    break;
  }
}
```